# Adding errorbars in ggplot Python

Tags: python, python-ggplot

Can't find a way of adding errorbars to a Python ggplot plot. The [following issue](https://github.com/yhat/ggplot/issues/25) has been neglected for over a year. Nothing in the [docs](http://ggplot.yhathq.com/docs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and found no solution. However I did find a way around it. You can use matplotlib in the style of ggplot. From there it's much easier to use error bars. I've attached an example of some code I used.

`plt.style.use('ggplot')`

This is an extract of one of my codes

`df2.gLongCrFiltered['mean'].plot(kind='bar', yerr=df2.gLongCrFiltered['std'])`

which returned this[image]

Comment: I thought matplotlib might be the answer. I'm reluctant to learn a whole new plotting library but it seems I have no choice!

Comment: There is a vast amount of support for it both here on SO and on their website. It's quite a nice piece of kit. There might be a way on ggplot but I searched for quite a while with no luck