# How to add error bars on a grouped barplot from a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

I have a [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) data frame **`df`** that has four columns: `Candidate`, `Sample_Set`, `Values`, and `Error`. The `Candidate` column has, say, three unique entries: `[X, Y, Z]` and we have three sample sets, such that `Sample_Set` has three unique values as well: `[1,2,3]`. The df would roughly look like this.

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'Candidate': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
        'Sample_Set': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
        'Values': [20, 10, 10, 200, 101, 99, 1999, 998, 1003],
        'Error': [5, 2, 3, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# display(df)
  Candidate  Sample_Set  Values  Error
0         X           1      20      5
1         Y           1      10      2
2         Z           1      10      3
3         X           2     200     30
4         Y           2     101     30
5         Z           2      99     30
6         X           3    1999     10
7         Y           3     998     10
8         Z           3    1003     10
```

I am using [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) to create a grouped barplot out of this with `x="Candidate"`, `y="Values"`, `hue="Sample_Set"`. All's good, until I try to add an error bar along the y-axis using the values under the column named `Error`. I am using the following code.

```
import seaborn as sns

ax = sns.factorplot(x="Candidate", y="Values", hue="Sample_Set", data=df,
                    size=8, kind="bar")
```

How do I incorporate the error?

I would appreciate a solution or a more elegant approach on the task.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As @ResMar pointed out in the comments, there seems to be no built-in functionality in seaborn to easily set individual errorbars.

If you rather care about the result than the way to get there, the following (not so elegant) solution might be helpful, which builds on `matplotlib.pyplot.bar`. The seaborn import is just used to get the same style.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def grouped_barplot(df, cat,subcat, val , err):
    u = df[cat].unique()
    x = np.arange(len(u))
    subx = df[subcat].unique()
    offsets = (np.arange(len(subx))-np.arange(len(subx)).mean())/(len(subx)+1.)
    width= np.diff(offsets).mean()
    for i,gr in enumerate(subx):
        dfg = df[df[subcat] == gr]
        plt.bar(x+offsets[i], dfg[val].values, width=width, 
                label="{} {}".format(subcat, gr), yerr=dfg[err].values)
    plt.xlabel(cat)
    plt.ylabel(val)
    plt.xticks(x, u)
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


cat = "Candidate"
subcat = "Sample_Set"
val = "Values"
err = "Error"

# call the function with df from the question
grouped_barplot(df, cat, subcat, val, err )
```

[image]

Note that by simply inversing the category and subcategory

```
cat = "Sample_Set"
subcat = "Candidate"
```

you can get a different grouping:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest extracting the position coordinates from `patches` attributes, and then plotting the error bars.

```py
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x="Candidate", y="Values", hue="Sample_Set")
x_coords = [p.get_x() + 0.5*p.get_width() for p in ax.patches]
y_coords = [p.get_height() for p in ax.patches]
ax.errorbar(x=x_coords, y=y_coords, yerr=df["Error"], fmt="none", c= "k")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- [seaborn](/questions/tagged/seaborn) plots generate error bars when aggregating data, however this data is already aggregated, and has a specified error column.
- The easiest solution is to use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) to create the [bar-chart](/questions/tagged/bar-chart) with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) and `kind='bar'`

  - [matplotlib](/questions/tagged/matplotlib) is used by default as the plotting backend, and the plot API has a `yerr` parameter, which accepts the following:

    - As a `DataFrame` or `dict` of errors with column names matching the `columns` attribute of the plotting DataFrame or matching the `name` attribute of the Series.
    - As a `str` indicating which of the columns of plotting `DataFrame` contain the error values.
    - As raw values (`list`, `tuple`, or `np.ndarray`). Must be the same length as the plotting `DataFrame`/`Series`.
- This can be accomplished by reshaping the dataframe from long form to wide form with [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)
- See [pandas User Guide: Plotting with error bars](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#plotting-with-error-bars)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.12`, `pandas 1.3.4`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`**

```py
# reshape the dataframe into a wide format for Values
vals = df.pivot(index='Candidate', columns='Sample_Set', values='Values')

# reshape the dataframe into a wide format for Errors
yerr = df.pivot(index='Candidate', columns='Sample_Set', values='Error')

# plot vals with yerr
ax = vals.plot(kind='bar', yerr=yerr, logy=True, rot=0, figsize=(6, 5))
_ = ax.legend(title='Sample Set', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.02), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

#### `vals`

```
Sample_Set   1    2     3
Candidate                
X           20  200  1999
Y           10  101   998
Z           10   99  1003
```

#### `yerr`

```
Sample_Set  1   2   3
Candidate            
X           5  30  10
Y           2  30  10
Z           3  30  10
```

Answer (score -3):

You can get close to what you need using pandas plotting functionalities: [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32967697/adding-errorbars-in-ggplot-python)

```
bars = data.groupby("Candidate").plot(kind='bar',x="Sample_Set", y= "Values", yerr=data['Error'])
```

This does not do exactly what you want, but pretty close. Unfortunately ggplot2 for python currently does not render error bars properly. Personally, I would resort to [R ggplot2](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/) in this case:

```
data <- read.csv("~/repos/tmp/test.csv")
data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(x=Candidate, y=Values, fill=factor(Sample_Set))) + 
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Values-Error, ymax=Values+Error), width=.1, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

Comment: Switching to R doesn't seem necessary here.